# OpenGL ES IOS Texture 2D drawing upside down

Tags: ios, opengl-es, texture2d

I am writing a small game (it is 2d) in IOS using Opengl as a way to get comfortable with opengl. I am using the Texture2D class from the CrashLanding demo. I am using this to generate text for the score. When the text is drawn it is upside down. In the code there is comments about the texture being loaded upside down but I can not find a way to render it the correct way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL and your image loading code do not agree on where the origin is. OpenGL starts in the lower left hand corner, while your picture starts in the upper right hand corner. You can apply a transform to the picture in your app like the CrashLanding demo does. Or even simpler pre flip the image in an editing program such as Photoshop. This will work if your image will only be used as an OpenGL texture in this app. If you need to display this same picture elsewhere you'll need to keep a non flipped version, or figure out how to apply the transform.

Comment: Thank you very much!! What the problem was,was that I was using some extra libraries that added some pre-existing transformation. I forgot about these. This was causing all of my problems.